# print full url template

Tags: theming, i18n-l10n, uri

I'm building a multi language site but I'm facing a problem with an url.
In my template i have the following print rule for an url `<?php print $base_url.'/#project';?>`
The base url only prints http://www.codedesign.be/#project withouth the language selector. url is normal url/nl/#project or www.codedesign.be/fr/#project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [url()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7) function to create URLs.

> Generates an internal or external URL.

This functions handles all complexity of creating an URL, including language prefix. url() handles exernal URLs too.

You can also use the [l()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) function to create anchor tags:

> Formats an internal or external URL link as an HTML anchor tag.
>
> This function correctly handles aliased paths and adds an 'active'
>   class attribute to links that point to the current page (for theming),
>   so all internal links output by modules should be generated by this
>   function if possible.

In your case you can use:

```
<?php print url('<front>', array('absolute' => TRUE, 'fragment' => 'project'));?>
```

Comment: Probably worth noting the OP will need to use `<front>` as the first param, and to have `'external' => TRUE` in the options array to get the full URL

Comment: could you help me out how to write my php code then?

Comment: Answer updated with code but keep i mind that is better to code in the template.php than in .tpl files.

Answer (score 0):

If `$base_url` doesn't append the language, you may use  this code

```
global $base_url;
global $language;
$url = $base_url."/".$language->name."/#peoject";
```

Comment: when I use this <?php global $base_url;global $language;$url = $base_url.$language->name."/#project";?> i get http://www.codedesign.be/nl/portfolio/droomevenementen and it needs to be http://www.codedesign.be/nl/#project

Comment: You can use the [`url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7) function @user2301868

Comment: @user2301868 I didn't get you! what is the problem with appending the language?

But as clive said you can also use `url()` function.